# I'm having a problem using discord.py, one of my commands won't get recognized

Tags: python, discord.py

Here's the thing, i'm using the latest version of discord.py to write a discord bot, and i'm stuck
I've made a custom help command and before that i have removed the old help command using this line:

```
client.remove_command("help")
```

Although when i run it, (it spits no errors btw) and try the command, it says

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found

Here's the full code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
client.remove_command("help")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready.')

client.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
        )
    embed.set_author(name='Help', value="Sends you this embed in a private message")
    embed.add_field(name='.ping', value="Shows the bot's current ping.", inline=False)

    await author.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} Check you dms, i've sent you a private message! *wink*")


client.run('TOKEN HERE')
```

Comment: When does the error: "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found" occure?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an "@" before `client.command(pass_context=True)`

This means that you do successfully remove the default help command but then because of that typo your custom help command is never created. So when you try to run the help command it says that it doesn't exist.

discord.py 1.4.0 documentation on defining a command: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html